# dependencies from private repository are not fetching even after using go mod tidy and go get "github.com/name/custom_repo"

Tags: go, module, dependencies

The issue was that I forked dependency repositories for version lock and pushed it into a private repository (github.com/shubhamgholave/packages /). Then created a go.mod with same github link as given above (github.com/shubhamgholave/packages).

[image: repository]

In main.go import section I said `import "github.com/shubhamgholave/packages/slacker` or slack(as all the required dependencies are inside packages like slacker, slack, websocket). But it keeps giving me errors when I try to `go get github.com/shubhamgholave/packages` or `go get github.com/shubhamgholave/package/slacker` or `go mod tidy`.

[image: errors]

I tried using `go mod tidy` and `go mod edit -replace="original/repo=custom_preivate_repo@version"` and also `go get github.com/shubhamgholave/packages/slacker` and same command until packages.

Comment: Please post the error messages as text instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue was that I forked dependency repositories for version lock and pushed it into a private repository

If for version lock, you can rely on the Go tool chain which will do it for you. See [Checksum database](https://go.dev/ref/mod#checksum-database).

If you want to ensure that all files used for a build are stored in a single file tree, you should use [Vendoring](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring) instead.

Your approach does work because the modules have their own `go.mod` file, which defines the import path of the modules. Placing a `go.mod` file in the root directory does not change this fact.